# mktime is not converting to the right date, why?

Tags: c

Using standard mktime() function from time.h library

```
tm Tm;
Tm.tm_year = 46;
Tm.tm_mon = 3-1;  // since month start with zero
Tm.tm_mday = 23;
Tm.tm_hour = 9;
Tm.tm_min = 3;
Tm.tm_sec = 38;

uint32_t epoch = mktime(&Tm);
```

`epoch` is 1458651818
going to: http://www.epochconverter.com  and entering 1458651818

outputs:

Tue 22 Mar 2016 09:03:38 AM EDT GMT-4:00 DST

I am setting day `Tm.tm_day = 23;`, not 22, why is my epoch converting to 23rd? What is the recommended way to fix it?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you want time_t, not uint32_t..

Comment: What is the type `Tm`? Is it an alias for `struct tm`?

Comment: As for your problem, what is the value of the `tm_isdst` member? Maybe you should initialize it?

Comment: `tm_mon` should be zero-based so if you want March it's 2, not 3.  And `tm_year` is years since 1900, not 1970.  There is no `tm_day` in `struct tm`.  Very curious about what this `Tm` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C language does not specify the epoch year and leaves it up to library implementation. I was assuming the EPOCH is 1970, but the particular library I was using sets their epoch to 1900. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what answer you were expecting.

I assume your `Tm` type is actually a `struct tm`.

When you set

```
Tm.tm_year = 46;
```

you are asking for the year 1946.

When you set

```
Tm.tm_mon = 3;
```

you are asking for April.  (tm_mon is 0-based.)

I assume you meant

```
Tm.tm_mday = 23;
```

(There is no `tm_day` member in `struct tm`.)

As Joachim Pileborg mentioned, for best results when calling `mktime` you should also set

```
Tm.tm_isdst = -1;
```

Finally, most systems measure time since 1970.  So 1946 is a negative time.  So when you assign `mktime`'s return value to an unsigned `epoch` variable, you're not going to get the right answer.

When I modify your code to assign `mktime`'s return value to a `time_t` variable, and print it, like this:

```
time_t epoch = mktime(&Tm);
printf("%ld\n", (long)epoch);
```

I get -747654982, which is what I'd expect.  (I'm on U.S. Eastern time; if you're in a different time zone you'll get a slightly different value.)

If you want to compute a time_t ("epoch") value for today's date, in 2016, use

```
Tm.tm_year = 2016 - 1900;
```

(which will give it the value 116).

One more question: Are you *sure* when you ran this code it computed `epoch` as 1458651818?  1458651818 corresponds to yesterday!  It has nothing to do with the year 1946, and it's not the answer I'd expect based on your `uint32_t` mistake, either.

(By the way, what system are you using?  Not all systems necessarily use a base year of 1970.)

Comment: Another note:  `mktime()` expects _all_ fields, except `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` to be initialized.  `struct tm` has at _least_ 9 fields - maybe more.  Best to zero fill all `tm Tm = {0};` and then fill individual fields as needed - before calling `mktime()`.  Then check its result against -1.

Comment: @chux Check its result against -1, and hope the date you were trying to convert wasn't 23:59:59 on December 31, 1969. :-) (But you're right, of course.)